# Scala: Convert RDD[LabelledPoint] to RDD[(Long,Vector)]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, vector, machine-learning

I have data in an `RDD[LabeledPoint]` (denoted as `sparse0.sparseData` in the code below)

I want to convert to `RDD[(Long,Vector)]` so I can run the LDA analysis in mllib package.

The best I can manage is a map to `RDD[(Long,Vector[Double])]` which does not compile when entered into the `LDA.run` method

Trying to map to `RDD[(Long,Vector)]` does not compile in the `.map` method. (error Vector takes type parameters)

The fact that my map method seems tortuous suggests I am missing something obvious. Any hints would be greatly appreciated

```
val mappedData:Map[Long,Vector[Double]]=sparse0.sparseData().collect().map
{
      var count:Int=0
  row =>
    count=count+1
    new Tuple2[Long,Vector[Double]](count,row.features.toArray.toVector)



}.toMap

val mappedRDD=spark.sparkContext.parallelize(mappedData.toSeq)

// Cluster the documents into three topics using LDA
val ldaModel = new LDA().setK(3).run(mappedRDD)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scala `Vector` is not the same as `mllib.linalg.Vector`. I'd `zipWithIndex`

```
val mappedRDD  = sparse0.sparseData().map(_.features).zipWithIndex.map(_.swap)
```

Comment: yup, you beat me to it :)

if my mappedData is typed with val mappedData:Map[Long,org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] everything works